# No access local wordpress website after PC formating

Tags: wp-admin

I created a wordpress website locally 4 months ago. One day, I decided to format my computer because it works very badly. After formatting, I installed Wampserver again for offline access, but to my amazement it does not work. I can no longer access the Dashboard of my site. What should I do in this case to solve the problem? how will I recover my previously created database on PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: check if database and files are still there or not? If not there, the answer is you can't recover

Comment: Don't you take a backup before formatting?